# Android market publishing

Tags: android

Well,I have a big problem because I put an android app on the market that is searcheble by this URL: 
"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=simple.notification.app1" and it does work but when I m going to Google Play and I search "Simple Notifications" the name of the app there is not my app published it passed more than 2 days and I dont know waht to do please help.I have tried everythin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shows up as the first result for me if you search **Simple Notification.app1** - You may need to rename or reconfigure your meta data relating to the upload, it seems to be searchable only via direct name right now.

Comment: @LucianBadita if you login to the play dev center where you uploaded your app, you should be able to amend the data surrounding your app, such as the description. It may not may not require a republish, I can't remember.

Comment: ther is some dat to amend but like name ,description as you said

Comment: @LucianBadita I tried a number of searches on the play store, your app always comes up if you add "app1" to the end of the search (such as simple notification app1), your solution will probably rely on finding where app1 is coming from and removing it from any data relating to the app

Comment: app1 is in the eclipse packages i will amend there thanks a lot

Comment: Look what i have done i renamed the packages and google did't let me to upload with others packages so i unplished the app and published a new one with other packages hope it will work i think it will take some time till will be publsihed

Comment: @LucianBadita cool. If it doesn't work - post your findings here and I'll look into the issue again for you

Answer (score 0):

Your app is on the market, but it's probably far down on the list. It will move up depending on its popularity and downloads. Give it time.